# Что может произойти при вызове оператора new std::string при инициализации членов-данных класса

Tags: c++, c++11

Что может произойти при вызове оператора **new std::string** при инициализации членов-данных класса (возможные нюансы) и как с этим бороться, псевдокод:

```
class StringPointer {
public:
    StringPointer(std::string *ptr) : 
        m_ptr( ptr ? ptr : new std::string ),
        m_owner ( ptr == nullptr )
    {}

    ~StringPointer() {
        if ( m_owner ) delete m_ptr;
    }

    std::string* operator->() {
        return m_ptr;
    }

    std::string operator*() {
        return *m_ptr;
    }

private:
    std::string *m_ptr;
    bool m_owner;
};
```

Тут некая защита от разыменования NULL -- при попытке это сделать класс конструирует внутри себя пустую строку. (Делает это в конструкторе)

```
std::string s1 = "Hello, world!";

StringPointer sp1(&s1);
StringPointer sp2(NULL);

std::cout << sp1->length() << std::endl;
std::cout << *sp1 << std::endl;
std::cout << sp2->length() << std::endl;
std::cout << *sp2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: А чего вы боитесь?... Что `new` сгенерирует исключение?

Comment: Плохое будет происходить в `std::string operator*` - каждый раз будет создаваться копия строки.

Comment: Самый главный вопрос - зачем это, если можно сделать просто `std::string`? А если так хочется указатель, почему не `std::unique_ptr<std::string>`?

Comment: Допустим оператор такой.

operator std::string*() {
    return m_ptr;
}

Что может произойти при создании объекта в конструкторе?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тоже подумал про `unique_ptr`, но что-то не соображу, как там реализовать аналог `StringPointer sp1(&s1);` из приведенного примера кода.